# Interpreting compressed SVG path command syntax

Tags: svg, svgo

I'm working with compressed SVG path data which has been output from SVGO, and I can't understand one part of a relative line-to command. The path itself looks like this (it's a triangle, and it displays correctly):

`<path d="M2107.49 3283.96l70.68 81.44 28.54-81.69-99.22.25z"/>`

Pulling apart the `d` attribute into commands, we get:

```
M: (Start coords) 2107.49 3283.96
l: (Relative line to coords) 70.68 81.44 28.54-81.69-99.22.25
z (close)
```

The piece I don't understand is the last 'pair' of the line-to commands: From what I understand, we should have 3 pairs of coordinates, which are either separated by a space `70.68 81.44`, or where negative, no space: `28.54-81.69` = `28.54`, `-81.69`. But what's going on in that last 'pair'? Does `-99.22.25` represent `-99.2` and `2.25`? How would I know how to split that?

SVGO is trying to squeeze every last byte out of its compression, so it's possibly taking advantage of some implied parsing rule I can't find a reference to. Does anyone know how to deal with that last pair?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [BNF in the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#paths-PathDataBNF)

> ...
>
> Similarly, for the string "M 0.6.5", the first coordinate of the "moveto" consumes the characters "0.6" and stops upon encountering the second decimal point because the production of a "coordinate" only allows one decimal point. The result is that the first coordinate will be "0.6" and the second coordinate will be ".5".

So -99.22.25 is -99.22 followed by .25

Comment: Ah, great. Thank you - I hadn't considered the leading zero could be omitted.